# Saving objects in array still overwriting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am currently working on saving objects in an array, the problem is that the data is not added but overwritten. Some ideas.

```
export function onClick(name: string, price: string) {
  let data = { name: name, price: price };
  //newData
  sessionStorage.setItem("newData", JSON.stringify(data));
  let newData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("newData"));
  //Cart
  let cartData = [];
  cartData.push(newData);
  sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartData));
  let cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
  console.log(cart); //todo LOG
}
```

I need this result:

```
[
    0: {name:'test1',price:'150'}
    1: {name:'test2',price:'180'}
    2: {name:'test3',price:'190'}
    3: {name:'test4',price:'150'}
    4: {name:'test5',price:'180'}
    5: {name:'test6',price:'190'}
]
```

Comment: //Cart
let cartData = [];

Should be out of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `cartData = []` out of function, Every time user click, you overriding `cartData`

```
//Cart
let cartData = [];

export function onClick(name: string, price: string) {
  let data = { name: name, price: price };
  //newData
  sessionStorage.setItem("newData", JSON.stringify(data));
  let newData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("newData"));
  cartData.push(newData);
  sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartData));
  let cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cart"));
  console.log(cart); //todo LOG
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with the original data in the storage, only overwriting it.

```
export function onClick(name: string, price: string) {
    let newData = {'name': name, 'price': price};

    //Cart
    let cartData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart'));
    cartData.push(newData);

    sessionStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartData));


    //some other place where you need to access the cart
    let cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('cart'));

    console.log(cart); //todo LOG
}
```